# How to not call the same Dear ImGui function several times per frame

Tags: imgui

I'm using this Dear ImGui code in a function called several times per frame, resulting in duplications of the called UI element.

```
ImGui::Begin("Hello World");
ImGui::SliderFloat("test", &foo, 0.0f, 100.0f);
ImGui::End();
```

Result:

[image]

How to correct this behaviour?
Can Dear ImGui be set to avoid this, or do I have to take care of this myself?

Comment: _"do I have to take care of this myself?"_ Yep. We're not yet ready for having programs design themselves from "what we want them to do". Did you try to put this in an `if( not flag ) { /* draw your thing */ flag = true; }` and reset the `flag` every frame?

Comment: _Why_ is this function called several times a frame? A function which is supposed to render should be called exactly once per frame.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I asked that because ImGUI knows when there is a new frame (ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame), so it could maybe have deal with it. 
@Vaillancourt: yes this is what I thought :)

Comment: @tkausl: I'm new to ImGUI but the render functions I'm aware of (ImGui::Render and ImGui::GetDrawData) are in my main loop, called 1 time / frame. But I could be wrong?

Comment: I'm talking about `I'm using this Dear ImGui code in a function called several times per frame`. Why is this function called several times per frame?

Comment: @tkausl: to make a debug tool in a function called several times per frame. I put the ImGUI code I showed in this function to directly access its variables but maybe it's bad design?

Comment: It looks to me like we don't have enough context to help you call this function only once per frame. You'll need to expand your code example so we can see where the multiple calls arise.

Comment: It's kind of weird because I thought imgui would not create multiple widgets with the same label, `"test"`. Also the system will not be bothered by anything in NewFrame because you are calling the window function every frame after NewFrame anyway

Comment: Originally I wanted to put Imgui code in situ, where I needed it. 
Then, to resolve these duplicate problems I first used a "new frame" flag, but I found this solution a bit cumbersome to apply everywhere in the engine. 
Finally I have found simpler to put all Imgui code into one class, with methods to display this or that Imgui window. This class is called one time in the main loop, and its methods use pointers to fetch the variables they need into the engine. 
Thank you all!